# maven not downloading google-gson

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml

I haved added the below lines in my pom.xml.Still I can't find gson-2.2.4.jar in my local maven repository.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
```

What can be the possible reason for this.? The version of Maven that I am using is

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_NZ, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: What's the error message? Where is your dependency declared? is it really `dependencies` or it is simply `dependencyManagement`?

Comment: what dependency? Do you mean to say that I have to declare gson-2.2.4 somewhere else as well other than the pom.xml file

Comment: I am just raising one possibility: you may have put it under `dependencyManagement` instead of `dependencies` inside the POM.  Anyway, the most important thing is, what is the error message? Or your project is built without any error?

Comment: @liv2hak Did you manage to fix this issue? I am also facing the same issue. But I can compile my project.

Comment: I had the same issue. But the comment of @AdrianShum solved the problem. I had the 'dependency' under 'dependencyManagement' instead of 'dependencies'.